# Prove that if $0 \lt x \lt y$ then $0 \lt y^{-1} \lt x^{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to prove the sentence above but I don't know where to go. I was able to prove the first part of the sentence ($0\lt x$), could someone help me?

Comment: That's simply not true. $0<x<y \implies 0<y^{-1}<x^{-1}$

Comment: This seems incorrect. For instance: $2< 3$, but $1/2 > 1/3$.

Comment: That statement is just false. **Edit:** It’s corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like what others have pointed out, the statement is not true, the right inequality should be $$0<y^{-1}<x^{-1}$$

Multiplying a positive number doesn't change the sign of inequality.

Just multiply everything by $\frac1{xy}$ and see what do you get.

Remark: there is nothing for you to prove in the first part, those are properties of $x$ that is given to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, take $$x=2,y=3$$ then we get $$2<3$$  but $$\frac{1}{2}>\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, I wrote it wrong. I've already edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $0<1<2$, however $1^{-1}=1$ and $2^{-1}=1/2$, therefore $0<1^{-1}\not<2^{-1}$. What you want is if $0<x<y$, then $0<y^{-1}<x^{-1}$. Try and division on the inequality $x<y$, see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. This function is decreasing. So for $\forall x > y > 0$ we have $\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{y}$.

Two way to show this function is decreasing:

1) Consider $f'(x)$

2) Use the definition : $\forall x > y > 0$ we have $f(x) < f(y)$ , so $x > y \rightarrow \frac{x}{y} > 1 \rightarrow \frac{1}{y} > \frac{1}{x}$